# vertical alignment in texstudio

Tags: latex

I am making a table with texstudio, and I have trouble with vertical alignment of the texts. When I have \hline, the text crosses the line.

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{lcccc}
\hline\hline
 & \textbf{$d_{(O_{1}-Zn/Mg)}(\SI{}{\angstrom})$} 
 & \textbf{$d_{(O_{2}-Zn/Mg)}(\SI{}{\angstrom})$} 
 & \textbf{$d_{(O_{3}-Zn/Mg)}(\SI{}{\angstrom})$} 
 & \textbf{$d_{(O_{\bot}-Zn/Mg)}(\SI{}{\angstrom})$} \\[1mm]
\hline 
\textbf{Pure HB-NWs} &  &  &  &   \\
\hline\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

And I have also enclosed the undesired result to make my point clear.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!
(La)TeX-related questions are better asked at [tex.se]. Your question has been flagged so that it gets migrated there.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using the [booktabs](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/booktabs) package which addresses rules and lines in tables quite well. See [its documentation](http://ftp.uniroma2.it/TeX/macros/latex/contrib/booktabs/booktabs.pdf) for some notes on table formatting and how to used it. In short, adding

```
\usepackage{booktabs}
```

to your preamble will let you use a number of new commands for rules in tables:

```
\toprule
\midrule
\bottomrule
```

combining these with your example gives a table looking as follows:
[image: booktabs style with additional spacing]

or, if you insist on using double rules at top and bottom:
[image: double rules with additional spacing]

In both cases I don't see the need for your additional '[1em]' space below the top line - without it things would look like this:
[image: booktabs style],
[image: double rules]

This will generate a pdf with all three examples to allow easy comparison:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}

Using \emph{booktabs} style rules:\\\vskip\baselineskip
\begin{tabular}{lcccc}
  \toprule
    & \textbf{$d_{(O_{1}-Zn/Mg)}(\SI{}{\angstrom})$} 
    & \textbf{$d_{(O_{2}-Zn/Mg)}(\SI{}{\angstrom})$}  \\[1mm]
  \midrule 
    \textbf{Pure HB-NWs} &  &  &  &   \\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\vskip\baselineskip
also works without the additional `[1mm]' spacing at the bottom of the line:
\vskip\baselineskip
\begin{tabular}{lcccc}
  \toprule
    & \textbf{$d_{(O_{1}-Zn/Mg)}(\SI{}{\angstrom})$} 
    & \textbf{$d_{(O_{2}-Zn/Mg)}(\SI{}{\angstrom})$} \\
  \midrule 
    \textbf{Pure HB-NWs} &  &  &  &   \\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\vskip\baselineskip
\vskip\baselineskip

Using \emph{double rules}:
\vskip\baselineskip
\begin{tabular}{lcccc}
  \midrule\midrule
    & \textbf{$d_{(O_{1}-Zn/Mg)}(\SI{}{\angstrom})$} 
    & \textbf{$d_{(O_{2}-Zn/Mg)}(\SI{}{\angstrom})$} \\[1mm]
  \midrule 
    \textbf{Pure HB-NWs} &  &  &  &   \\
  \midrule\midrule
\end{tabular}
\vskip\baselineskip
and again without the additional `[1mm]' spacing at the bottom of the line:
\vskip\baselineskip
\begin{tabular}{lcccc}
  \midrule\midrule
    & \textbf{$d_{(O_{1}-Zn/Mg)}(\SI{}{\angstrom})$} 
    & \textbf{$d_{(O_{2}-Zn/Mg)}(\SI{}{\angstrom})$} \\
  \midrule 
    \textbf{Pure HB-NWs} &  &  &  &   \\
  \midrule\midrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

On a side note: the 'siunitx' package you're using provides a '\si' command specifically for printing only units, rather than using the '\SI' command with an empty argument; i.e. you might want to use the following:

```
\si{\angstrom}
```

rather than:

```
\SI{}{\angstrom}
```